# How to get a guest account in ightdm on debian? Enabled it in lightdm.conf but nothing happened. Is something else required as well?

Tags: linux, debian

How want an option for guest session in my user list in lightdm but I don't get one. I am talking about something like ubuntu and its flavours used to have back in the days.

This is the my `lightdm.conf` seat

```
[Seat:*]
#type=local
#pam-service=lightdm
#pam-autologin-service=lightdm-autologin
#pam-greeter-service=lightdm-greeter
#xserver-backend=
#xserver-command=X
#xmir-command=Xmir
#xserver-config=
#xserver-layout=
#xserver-allow-tcp=false
#xserver-share=true
#xserver-hostname=
#xserver-display-number=
#xdmcp-manager=
#xdmcp-port=177
#xdmcp-key=
#unity-compositor-command=unity-system-compositor
#unity-compositor-timeout=60
#greeter-session=example-gtk-gnome
greeter-hide-users=false
greeter-allow-guest=true
#greeter-show-manual-login=false
#greeter-show-remote-login=true
#user-session=default
allow-user-switching=true
allow-guest=true
#guest-session=
#session-wrapper=lightdm-session
#greeter-wrapper=
#guest-wrapper=
display-setup-script=xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --right-of LVDS1
#display-stopped-script=
#greeter-setup-script=
#session-setup-script=
#session-cleanup-script=
#autologin-guest=false
#autologin-user=
#autologin-user-timeout=0
#autologin-in-background=false
#autologin-session=
#exit-on-failure=false
```

But despite all this I do not get an option for a guest user. I read the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM#Enabling_guest_sessions) for guest session and from what I think I am missing the guest script or something.

What am I missing? If Anybody has any idea please let me know...

Currently using Xfce4 on debian buster.

Comment: I have the same problem on Mint LDDE4 with cinnamon.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing

```
sudo sh -c 'printf "[Seat:*]\nallow-guest=true\n" > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-enable-guest.conf'
```

This might enable guest session on your system

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me what this command  will do? I do not want to execute unknown commands. My  guess is that it sets the ```allow-guest``` property to be true. But I have already set it to true in my seat settings.